# Is it possible to use CSS transform property only to adjust an element's width property without stretching it?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

What I want to achieve is to use only `transform` on `#b:hover` to implement the very behavior of `#a:hover`, here is the code:

```css
div#a, div#b {
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  background:#ccc;
}

div#a:hover {
  width:150px;
}

div#b:hover {
  transform:scaleX(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Test1</div>

<div id="b">Test2</div>
```

There are now two problems:

1. The text is stretched.
2. The `div` is not expanding from the left point but from the center so it breaks out its container on its left side.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why? What you're asking for is a thing that `transform` is not designed to do.

Comment: ... except the answer below is pretty cool

Comment: Why does it have to be transform? Why not `width`?

Comment: @ray @Pointy because in the Performance report, `width` gives a `LayoutShift` penalty of Web Vitals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can consider and extra wrapper you can do it

```css
div#a, div#b {
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  background:#ccc;
}

div#a:hover {
  width:150px;
}

div#b:hover {
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
  transform-origin: left; /* change the origin to be left */
}

div#b:hover > div {
  transform: scaleX(calc(1/1.5)); /* the opposite transform to keep the text */
  transform-origin: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Test1</div>

<div id="b"><div>Test2</div></div>
```